# Where can I find Rspec + Capybara 'Getting Started' guides?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, tdd, rspec, capybara

I've been meaning to get into testing. After reading about a few testing frameworks (test::unit, Rspec, etc). I've decided give Rspec and Capybara a try.

I'd like to understand how experienced developers utilize these libraries properly. Which in-turn will help me write better application code and find bugs or little errors in the smallest cracks in the application.

Approaching this as a total TDD nooby. What online sources have you come across to help you learn about Rspec + Capybara. I found this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara?autoplay=true), which is a good starting point. Are there any other sources / articles I should be reading?

I came across [The Rspec Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379), which is great for Rspec, but touches more on Cucumber examples.

In addition, how can I find out all the functions available for Capybara. i.e. fill_in, click_link, etc. The [Github page](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) mentions a few, but not all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also use Rspec with Capybara, and i get along very well with this references:

- Action methods: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions
- Find methods: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders
- Match methods: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh, if only I'd found this sooner! /facepalm  I've been looking for documentation about Capybara for a few days now and completely overlooked the rdoc link on the GitHub page.